# how to warm up page cache in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm executing `allShortestPaths` query in `neo4j.After` a lot of tests, I have found that when executing the `allShortestPaths` query for the first time, it takes about 2~3 seconds, but when executing the same query again, it always takes less than 500ms.

After studying the neo4j documentation, I have known it has the page cache system. In neo4j-operations-manual, it says "When Neo4j starts up, its page cache is empty and needs to warm up",

**I am wondering how to warm up the page cache manually,and what's the mechanism of the page cache.**

**How to guarantee the first query execution cost is less than 500ms?

Total nodes : 0.16 Billion nodes

Total relationships : around 0.16 Million relationships 

Index on :E(eid)**

A sample of the query is as follow:

`"MATCH (node1:E { eid:"a9c2f114-796f-4934-a2d0-04bb3345e1d2" }),(node2:E { eid:"01968dd2-1ed6-472d-82e9-be7701036b3b" }), p = allShortestPaths((node1)-[*]-(node2))
RETURN p LIMIT 25"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to install the [APOC Procedures library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/1.1.0), it has all kinds of great and useful tools, including a [warmup procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_warmup).

Comment: I have view the guide.          CALL apoc.warmup.run()
Warmup the node and relationship page-caches by loading one page at a time.                I am wondering what "loading one page at a time" means,dose it loading all nodes and relationships into memmory at a time.       My neo4j database is about 40G, should i prepare more than 40G free RAM for the page cache

Comment: I have use CALL apoc.warmup.run.The result is as follow:  
pageSize nodesPerPage nodesTotal nodesLoaded nodesTime relsPerPage relsTotal relsLoaded relsTime totalTime
8192 546 156255221 286182 21 240 167012639 695886 8 30  
It only cache part of nodes and relations,but what i want is caches all the nodes and relation

Comment: i also encounter same, i have lots of ram, but it doesnt cache all the nodes. @Leeon have u solved this?

Comment: @WantIt all i have known is that the cache mechanism is the provided by linux or windows,and i think linux will do better in cache,but i haven't done enough tests. To guarantee the query performance, you should do some query yourself after you start neo4j,and the OS will cache the nodes itself. I haven't found any tool to help me do that ,I will try to find out better solutions,like making a small tool. 
hope it helps you.If you find some useful tool please tell me.