# Load Neo4J in memory on demand for heavy computations

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, in-memory-database

*How could I load Neo4J into memory on demand?*

On different stages of my long running jobs I'm persisting nodes and relationships to Neo4J. So Neo4J should be on disk, since it may consume too much memory and I don't know when I gonna run read queries against it.

But at some point (only once) I will want to run pretty heavy read query  against my Neo4J server, and it have very poor performance (hours). As a solution I want to load all Neo4J to RAM for better performance.

*What is the best option for it? Should I use run disk or there are any better solutions?*

### P.S.

Query with `[r:LINK_REL_1*2]` works pretty fast, `[r:LINK_REL_1*3]` works 17 seconds, `[r:LINK_REL_1*4]` works more than 5 minutes, even do not know how much, since I have 5 minutes timeout. But I need `[r:LINK_REL_1*2..4]` query to perform in reasonable time.

### My heavy query explanation

```
PROFILE
MATCH path = (start:COLUMN)-[r:LINK_REL_1*2]->(col:COLUMN) 
WHERE start.ENTITY_ID = '385' 
WITH path UNWIND NODES(path) AS col
WITH path, 
COLLECT(DISTINCT col.DATABASE_ID) as distinctDBs
WHERE LENGTH(path) + 1 = SIZE(distinctDBs)
RETURN path
```

[image]

### Updated query with explanation (got the same performance in tests)

```
PROFILE
MATCH (start:COLUMN)
WHERE start.ENTITY_ID = '385' 
MATCH path = (start)-[r:LINK_REL_1*2]->(col:COLUMN)
WITH path, REDUCE(dbs = [], col IN NODES(path) | 
  CASE WHEN col.DATABASE_ID in dbs 
       THEN dbs 
       ELSE dbs + col.DATABASE_ID END) as distinctDbs
WHERE LENGTH(path) + 1 = SIZE(distinctDbs)
RETURN path
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by 'I want to load all Neo4J to RAM'?  Do you need on demand entire Neo4j graph in memory?

Comment: What is the query  you're running? There is none that should run for hours.

Comment: Also in APOC there are some graph algorithm impelmentations that can load (parts) of the graph into a pure in-memory structure to run algorithms on.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh I think Neo4J should perform better if I'll load graph into JVM

Comment: @MichaelHunger  I updated my question. It's so slow due a huge number of permutations - `[r:FRIENDSHIP_REL*3]` returns 50,000+ paths. But I need `[r:FRIENDSHIP_REL*2..5]`

Comment: @MichaelHunger could you pls provide more details? I need to load in-memory only `:Person` nodes and `:FRIENSHIP_REL` relationships

Comment: I'd personally see if we can optimize your query. I have a feeling that the UNWIND is the poison pill in this one. Also, you may want to EXPLAIN your query, and paste in the expanded plan it returns. Lastly...do you really need to return all 50k+ paths? Or is there some limit we can apply, or smaller slice of data?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I've updated my question, please take a look

Comment: So it is unrelated to the data, just to the number of paths, are you only interested in the longest paths? Can you share your database (looks like db-metadata) ? michael at neo4j dot com

Comment: You might want to look into apoc's path expand with a NODE_GLOBAL configuration or a custom procedure.

Comment: @MichaelHunger please more details about apoc's path expand? How it would help me?

Answer (score 1):

APOC procedures has [apoc.warmup.run()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_warmup), which may get much of Neo4j into cached memory. See if that will make a difference.

Comment: is APOC supported at Neo4J 2.1.7? I've read your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071324/how-to-warm-up-page-cache-in-neo4j/39071447#39071447, but comments below say APOC loads only part of graph in-memory. I've not too =big but very dense graph, and not sure if partial load will gelp me a lot

Comment: No, I believe custom procedures were only introduced with Neo4j 3.0, so you wouldn't be able to use APOC.

Comment: is there any other options for pre 3.0 versions? Also could you please suppose how much speed up could I expect from loading graph to JVM?

Comment: actually I gonna make a proof of concept. Could you please help me to figure out how to load only `:Person` nodes and `:FRIENDSHIP_REL` relationships with `apoc.warmup.run()`?

Comment: couldn't I load Neo4J to memory with big page size? I saw similar questions dated by 2012, but they do not describe how did they manage to load graph to RAM

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a query in which the path contains only :Persons from distinct countries. Is this right?

If so, I think we can find a better query that can do this without hanging.

First, let's go for low-hanging fruit and see if avoiding the UNWIND can make a difference.

PROFILE or EXPLAIN the query and see if any numbers look significantly different compared to the original query.

```
MATCH (start:PERSON)
WHERE start.ID = '385' 
MATCH path = (start)-[r:FRIENDSHIP_REL*2..5]->(person:PERSON)
WITH path, REDUCE(countries = [], person IN NODES(path) | 
  CASE WHEN person.country in countries 
       THEN countries 
       ELSE countries + person.COUNTRY_ID END) as distinctCountries
WHERE LENGTH(path) + 1 = SIZE(distinctCountries)
RETURN path
```

Comment: I see you changed the data in the query. Let me know if you want me to change this to your COLUMN and database id model.

Comment: no, that absolutelly ok to stay with old names. Thank you! I will test your query in half an hour

Comment: Just saw the updated plan, looks like the only thing we avoid when removing UNWIND is multiplying the rows we're working with somewhere in the middle, db hits remain the same. I'm guessing execution times are about the same too.

Comment: yeah, I've just finished tests - execution time remains the same